# Can the same LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder instance be used by multiple channels?

Tags: java, netty

I am using Netty to process a protocol whose messages have a variable length field in the header. The LengthFieldBasedFrameDecoder proves to be perfect for this requirement.

Given that this is completely the same for every channel (actual processing of the contents is done by a subsequent handler in the pipeline) is it thread safe to use a singleton of this class rather than creating a new one for each channel?

What if the frame gets fragmented, and needs to be reassembled, does it keep separate ByteBuf instances for each Channel or is there a risk of getting data corrupted?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nope you need to create a new instance per Channel. All handlers that can be used by multiple Channels as marked as `@Sharable`.